# Issue with touch -t command when setting specific dates

Tags: command-line, bash, ls, date

I'm encountering an issue when using the touch -t command in the terminal. My goal is to adjust the access and modification dates of a file named "testShell00" to a specific date in the format MMDDhhmm[.ss]. However, I'm getting unexpected results.

Here are some examples of what I'm doing:

This command works as expected, displaying the date in the desired format (month, day, and hour):

```
touch -a -m -t 12180130.09 testShell00
```

Result of ls -l:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 jonatha  staff  40 Dec 18 01:30 testShell00
```

However, when using a different date, the result shows the full year, even though I provided only month, day, and hour:

```
touch -a -m -t 06012342.00 testShell00
```

Result of ls -l:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 jonatha  staff  40 Jun  1  2023 testShell00
```

I'm confused about why the second example is not displaying the date in the desired format (month, day, and hour) and instead shows the full year.

Could someone explain the reason for this behavior and how I can correct it to get the desired format?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The `ls` command tries to be "smart". Instead, use the `stat testShell00` command to see detailed meta info about your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
man ls
```

> Log Format: If the modification time of the file is more than 6 months in the past or future, and the -D or -T are not specified, then the year of the last modification is displayed in place of the hour and minute fields.

it's not you, it's them. kinda. regardless, it's an ls formatting rule.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ls` to inspect file metadata is where you went wrong. Use `stat` instead. Read `man stat`. Try: `stat -c '%n %t' testShel00`.